# Order of execution of shell commands

Tags: shell

if i have a shell command executed in piped and redirection mode.

```
Cmd1  | cmd2   | cmd3  > cmd4  <  cmd5   | cmd6   > cmd7  > cmd8   | cmd9
```

How does the order execute?

i am trying to write a C shell program to achieve this.
I am thinking like

```
Cmd1  | cmd2
Cmd2 | cmd3
Cmd3 -> cmd4
Cmd5 -> cmd4
Cmd5 | cmd6
Cmd6 -> cmd7
Cmd7 -> cmd8
Cmd8 | cmd9
```

Where | are writing and reading to pipe descriptors, and then -> are file read/write operations.

It does not work.
when i mean cmd, it can be an actual shell command in the place of it, or just a filename if redirection comes there..

can you help me understand in what order should i execute this?

Comment: I am not sure you correctly posted the output and input. You have `> cmd 7`  - it will redirect output to a file named `cmd` (__without__ the `7`) and `7` will be passed as argument. There will be no `Cmd 6 -> cmd7`, where will be `cmd6 7 > cmd`. Please make sure that spaces between characters and big and small letters (`cmd` vs `Cmd`, it's not the same) are in the proper places in your post.

Comment: Ignoring the apparent confusion about redirections for the moment: if you execute `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`, the order of execution is not specified except as determined by the data flow.  If `cmd3` ignores its input, it is entirely possible that it will completely finish before `cmd1` even begins.  If the output of `cmd1` fits entirely in the pipe buffer, it is quite possible that cmd1 will terminate before cmd2 begins.

Comment: Fortunately, for the purposes of writing a shell that executes the commands, you don't care.  The shell should just set up the pipes and execute the processes and let the operating system worry about scheduling.

Comment: when i mean cmd<x> or cmd <x>, it can be an actual shell command, or just a filename if redirection comes there. Ignore spaces between cmd and x for now.

Comment: As you were told before -- the shell is not responsible for order of execution. All parts of a pipeline run simultaneously.

Comment: ...though the way you're mixing pipes and redirections in the sample above makes no sense at all. Each process can only have one stdin and one stdout; when you specify both a pipeline and a redirection to be stdin to the same process, only one of those two directives can actually be honored.